# Gracenote php throwing error "A cURL error that wasn't a timeout or HTTP400 response."

Tags: gracenote

The Php-Gracenote library was working fine up until last week. But since then It has started showing the error as mentioned above. I put the latest version of the code from Rich Adams' repo but it still shows the same error. Has anyone seen a similar error? what could be the reason? Nothing has changed( like php-curl or openssl updates) in my server that could have caused such an error.

Comment: The only likely issue may be because of SSL v3.

Comment: Part of the error output from php-gracenote will be the error code from cURL. Check the extra information in the exception (looks like "ext=XX" where XX is a number). You can use that number to lookup the error here http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html to see why cURL is failing.